# Calculator variable multiplications NaN result (more than 2 variables)

Tags: javascript

So im trying to make a calculator to get into an IT school. But I cant seem to figure out why I get NaN as my answer.

What im supposed to make is a calculator with a feat, the feat being that you can also guess what the answer'll be. Im stuck trying to figure out why I keep getting NaN as an answer to all my multiplications.

The reason why there is 2 number3's in my var: product. that is because I found out I needed to have it in the multiplication to do the if statement. number3 is the one you guess with[this is how it looks, i translated the image if anyone was wondering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzFGm.png)

This is really bugging me since I like doing this but I cant seem to figure it out.

function CalculateProduct() {
var product = parseInt(number1) * parseInt(number2) * parseInt(number3) / parseInt(number3)

```
var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;

var nummer2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;

var number3 = document.getElementById("number3").value

var owncalculation= document.getElementById("owncalculation");

var uitkomst = document.getElementById("uitkomst");

if (number3 == product) {
    document.getElementById("owncalculation").innerHTML="The answer you put in was correct"
   } else {
    document.getElementById("owncalculation").innerHTML="The answer you put in was false"
   }

   if (Getal3 == product) {
    owncalculation.style.color = "green"
   } else {
    owncalculation.style.color = "red"
   }
   


result.innerHTML = "The answer to " + Getal1 + " * " + Getal2 + " = " + product;
```

}

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <pre>
        <h1>Js Rekenmachine</h1>
        Voer een getal in:        <input type="number" id="Getal1">

        Voer een tweede getal in: <input type="number" id="Getal2">

        Zelf berekende uitkomst:  <input type="number" id="Getal3">

        <p id="uitkomst">De uitkomst is:</p>

        <span id="eigenberekening">Het door jou berekende antwoord 
 is:</span>

        
        
        <button type="button"

        class="btn btn-success btn-lg"
        onclick="BerekenSom()">Bereken som</button>  
        
        <button type="button"

        class="btn btn-success btn-lg"
        onclick="BerekenProduct()">Bereken Product</button>  
          </div>
    </pre>

 <script src="./app.js"></script>   

</body>
</html>

function BerekenProduct() { 

var Getal1 = document.getElementById("Getal1").value;
var Getal2 = document.getElementById("Getal2").value;
var Getal3 = document.getElementById("Getal3").value

var product = parseInt(Getal1) * parseInt(Getal2) 

document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = product

uitkomst.innerHTML = "Het product van " + Getal1 + " * " + Getal2 + " = " + product;

if (Getal3 == product) {
    document.getElementById("eigenberekening").innerHTML="Het door jou berekende antwoord is goed"
   } else {
    document.getElementById("eigenberekening").innerHTML="Het door jou berekende antwoord is fout"
   }

   if (Getal3 == product) {
    eigenberekening.style.color = "green"
   } else {
    eigenberekening.style.color = "red"
   }

}
```

[image: results]

Comment: Is it possible to share the HTML?

Comment: @dram95 im trying my hardest to find out how i can post the code without going over the limit

Comment: @dram95 i edited my post to fit it. sorry for not translating, let me know if i need to translate it otherwise

Answer (score 0):

#### Make sure to create the variables *before* you calculate the product

There was also a typo `var number2` misspelled as `var nummer2`.

```js
function CalculateProduct() { 

var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
var number3 = document.getElementById("number3").value

var product = parseInt(number1) * parseInt(number2) 

document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = product

}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number1" ><br>
<input type="number" id="number2" ><br>
<input type="number" id="number3" ><br>
<div id="product" ></div><br>

<button onclick="CalculateProduct()">Calc</button>
```

#### Using your code

I have fixed the two errors, and marked them in the code below:

```js
function BerekenProduct() {

  var Getal1 = document.getElementById("Getal1").value;
  var Getal2 = document.getElementById("Getal2").value;
  var Getal3 = document.getElementById("Getal3").value

  var product = parseInt(Getal1) * parseInt(Getal2)

  // Error 1. This line is no longer needed, because you don't have a cell with id `product`
  // document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = product

  // Error 2. This line was just `uitkomst.innerHTML = ...` in your code, but there is no Javascript variable called `uitkomst` in your code
  document.getElementById("uitkomst").innerHTML = "Het product van " + Getal1 + " * " + Getal2 + " = " + product;


  if (Getal3 == product) {
    document.getElementById("eigenberekening").innerHTML = "Het door jou berekende antwoord is goed"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("eigenberekening").innerHTML = "Het door jou berekende antwoord is fout"
  }

  if (Getal3 == product) {
    eigenberekening.style.color = "green"
  } else {
    eigenberekening.style.color = "red"
  }

}
```

```html
<pre>
        <h1>Js Rekenmachine</h1>
        Voer een getal in:        <input type="number" id="Getal1">

        Voer een tweede getal in: <input type="number" id="Getal2">

        Zelf berekende uitkomst:  <input type="number" id="Getal3">

        <p id="uitkomst">De uitkomst is:</p>

        <span id="eigenberekening">Het door jou berekende antwoord 
 is:</span>

        
        
        <button type="button"

        class="btn btn-success btn-lg"
        onclick="BerekenSom()">Bereken som</button>  
        
        <button type="button"

        class="btn btn-success btn-lg"
        onclick="BerekenProduct()">Bereken Product</button>  
          </div>
    </pre>
```

Comment: yeah thats my bad, i translated it from dutch to english. I did try to fix it in dutch but the same problem still arised

Comment: I don't understand. In this snippet above, is the product working correctly? If so, what is different about your local code?

Comment: In my local code the only difference is the variables, the rest is just as it is in english.

I'm supposed to make it so that theres three boxes, in the first one you put a number, say 7. In the second box you put in another number, say 3. 
The third an final box is supposed to be what you think the answer is going to be. in this case 10.

Once you press the "solve" button you see: The answer of this question is 10, and below that is supposed to be: you guessed correctly. The only answers I get are like 2 * 2 =NaN or 2 * 2 = undefined

Comment: There must be other differences, because it is working correctly here and not in your code. I suggest the following: (1) Notice that the 2*2 = NaN is _already_ wrong, before any thought for your guessing. (2) Therefore produce a trimmed version of your local code, omiting everything other than reading two numbers and calculating the product and displaying them. (3) Do it by editing it into an extra section at the bottom of your question, by inserting a snippet with the `<>` icon.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! really saved me there. I didnt quite get how I could make a snippet so i posted it at the bottom with results below that.

Might I ask how do i get rid of the little 20 below the three boxes? 

And why did you use parseInt instead of parseFloat?

Comment: @ProfDFrancis For the sum I have an error when I run the snippet : {
  "message": "ReferenceError: BerekenSom is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 1,
  "colno": 1
}

Answer (score 0):

EDIT WITH A SECOND SNIPPET!

Here is your homework, I had time to loose ;)

I don't understand dutch, so I tried my best.

If you have question, feel free to comment.

Have a nice day.

```js
        function Bereken(operator) { 
            var Getal1 = document.getElementById("Getal1").value;
            var Getal2 = document.getElementById("Getal2").value;
            var Getal3 = document.getElementById("Getal3").value;
            var juistAntwoord = document.getElementById("uitkomst");
            var antwoord = document.getElementById("eigenberekening");
            var calc = document.getElementById("calc");
            var product;
            
            if(operator==="product"){
                product = parseInt(Getal1) * parseInt(Getal2);
                calc.textContent = "product van " + Getal1 + " x " + Getal2 + " = " + product;
            }
            if(operator==="sum"){
                product = parseInt(Getal1) + parseInt(Getal2);
                calc.textContent = "som van " + Getal1 + " + " + Getal2 + " = " + product;
            }
            
            juistAntwoord.textContent = "De uitkomst is: " + product;
            antwoord.textContent = "Het door jou berekende antwoord is : " + Getal3
            if (Getal3 == product) {
                antwoord.innerHTML="Het door jou berekende antwoord is goed";
                antwoord.className = "juist";
            } else {
                antwoord.innerHTML="Het door jou berekende antwoord is fout";
                antwoord.className = "fout";
            }
        }
```

```css
        .juist{
            color:#009900;
        }
        .fout{
            color:#990000;
        }
```

```html
        <h1>Js Rekenmachine</h1>
        <p>Voer een getal in:        <input type="number" id="Getal1"></p>

        <p>Voer een tweede getal in: <input type="number" id="Getal2"></p>

        <p>Zelf berekende uitkomst:  <input type="number" id="Getal3"></p>

        <p id="uitkomst">De uitkomst is:</p>
        <p id="calc"></p>

        <h2 id="eigenberekening">Het door jou berekende antwoord is:</h2>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="Bereken('sum')">Bereken som</button>  
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="Bereken('product')">Bereken Product</button>
```

Same code with - and / operators :

```js
        function Bereken(operator) { 
            var Getal1 = document.getElementById("Getal1").value;
            var Getal2 = document.getElementById("Getal2").value;
            var Getal3 = document.getElementById("Getal3").value;
            var juistAntwoord = document.getElementById("uitkomst");
            var antwoord = document.getElementById("eigenberekening");
            var calc = document.getElementById("calc");
            var product;
            
            if(operator==="product"){
                product = parseInt(Getal1) * parseInt(Getal2);
                calc.textContent = "product van " + Getal1 + " x " + Getal2 + " = " + product;
            }
            if(operator==="sum"){
                product = parseInt(Getal1) + parseInt(Getal2);
                calc.textContent = "som van " + Getal1 + " + " + Getal2 + " = " + product;
            }
            if(operator==="aftrekken"){
                product = parseInt(Getal1) - parseInt(Getal2);
                calc.textContent = "afftrek van " + Getal1 + " - " + Getal2 + " = " + product;
            }
            if(operator==="verdeling"){
                product = parseInt(Getal1) / parseInt(Getal2);
                calc.textContent = "afftrek van " + Getal1 + " - " + Getal2 + " = " + product;
            }
            
            juistAntwoord.textContent = "De uitkomst is: " + product;
            antwoord.textContent = "Het door jou berekende antwoord is : " + Getal3
            
            if (Getal3 == product) {
                antwoord.innerHTML="Het door jou berekende antwoord is goed";
                antwoord.className = "juist";
            } else {
                antwoord.innerHTML="Het door jou berekende antwoord is fout";
                antwoord.className = "fout";
            }
        }
```

```css
        .juist{
            color:#009900;
        }
        .fout{
            color:#990000;
        }
```

```html
    <h1>Js Rekenmachine</h1>

    <p>Voer een getal in:        <input type="number" id="Getal1"></p>
    <p>Voer een tweede getal in: <input type="number" id="Getal2"></p>
    <p>Zelf berekende uitkomst:  <input type="number" id="Getal3"></p>
    <p id="uitkomst">De uitkomst is:</p>
    <p id="calc"></p>

    <h2 id="eigenberekening">Het door jou berekende antwoord is:</h2>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="Bereken('sum')">Bereken som</button>  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="Bereken('product')">Bereken Product</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="Bereken('aftrekken')">Bereken Aftrekken</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="Bereken('verdeling')">Bereken Verdeling</button>
```

Comment: 1/ Prefer to add EventListeners in place of adding onClick in an element!
2/ You don't need two different functions like BerekenProduct and BerekenSom, just pass the operation as an argument in one function.

Comment: Wow, I just woke up to find this, you're amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: might I ask one more thing? Is this aplicable to minus and divisions? And so do I just copy and paste and change it to divisions / subtractions?

Comment: Yes, just do it man! And if the answer is correct, please mark it as solved.

Comment: Hi! so I just put in the code you sent in! The thing is when I type in a prompt, say first box 2, second one 10, then the third one 20 to guess what its gonna be, and I then press Bereken Product. It doesn't show either "het door jou berekende antwoord is goed", or "Product van 2 x 10 = 20". I use Visual Studio Code and Opera GX for my browser, is something wrong on my end?

Comment: No problem here with Opera 94.0.4606.38 (x86_64)
Where do you put your code?
In the head section or at the end of the body???

If it works in the snippet it must work on your side or the code is not well formated.

Comment: I made an extra visual studio code window, and put the function in an app.js.  I put the Js Rekenmachine part into index html and put 

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
      </head>
above the Js rekenmachine part, and the colors I put into a style.css folder

Comment: I see my mistake and sorry for wasting your time. I never put the code you gave me into a body, inside the html (if it works like that) I also gave it the script src of app.js, it works now! im going to try and make it work with divisions and subtractions! Thank you so so much for your input and help!

Comment: The code is edited in a second snippet so it support +, x, -, and /

Comment: I did it! all thanks to the help I got, I just turned it in and am just so grateful to everyone who helped me. Have a nice day! (oh and, how do I make a question solved?)

Comment: If you look at this image : http://tatactic.be/solved.jpeg there's a little v that you can click to accept the answer. Do you see it?